How do I connect cd4010b as inverter for IOWR signal
Following with the post Latch LS374 works for sometimes and doesn't work at all next clocks
I'm planning to use LS373 instead of LS374.
I need to invert the IOWR signal, I only have that inverter
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4010b.pdf?ts=1722598160395&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F
The pins configuration is confusing me, how can I connect the IOWR to that pins of CD4009UBE so that I invert the signal.

Which one is it, CD4010B or CD4009UBE?

@Justme CD4009UBE

Why not use a more suitable 74hct14?

What specifically confuses you? The data sheet is clear about the pins, the 4009 has 6 inverters. Use one of them to invert the signal. Make sure you connect the inputs of the other 5 to a defined level, for example ground or supply. -- Please [edit] your question to correct the device number. Do you have difficulties with numbers? In one of your other questions around your project you wrote 8080 instead of 8086. But numbers are so important in engineering.

Additionally, are you aware that the 4000 series is quite slow? The data sheet shows several tens of nanoseconds propagation delay (at assumed 5V supply) and even more transition time. The data sheet also recommends 4049 and 4069, resp. A better choice is the 74HC14, which is CMOS compatible and fast. -- Anyway, we discussed the issue of '373 vs '374 already, and I believe your realization has some general issues not yet discovered.
